# Brain js prediction

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, brain.js

I'm trying to create ML with Brain.js that takes as input a number and outputs its count of significant digits.

**Examples:**

Input: 234 Output:3

Input: 2413 Output: 4

Input: 1 Output 1

```html
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/harthur-org/brain.js/aabe8cc2/browser.js'></script>

<script>


const network = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

//Only simple test data provided for now

network.train([
    { input: { Num: 2 }, output: { SigFigs: 1 } },
    { input: { Num: 12 }, output: { SigFigs: 2 } },
    { input: { Num: 432 }, output: { SigFigs: 3 } },
    { input: { Num: 1358 }, output: { SigFigs: 4 } },
    { input: { Num: 98 }, output: { SigFigs: 2 } },
    { input: { Num: 9123 }, output: { SigFigs: 4} },
    { input: { Num: 14 }, output: { SigFigs: 2} },
    { input: { Num: 763 }, output: { SigFigs: 3} },
], {
  log: true,
  iterations: 1e6,
  errorThresh: 0.00001
});

const result = network.run({ Num: 43 });

console.log(result); //SigFigs: 0.9999999396415676
//Expected output: 2

</script>
```

The result is completely no sense for me. I expect something like 2 and in worse case some other number. What I am doing wrong and what should I do to get the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the output key as the number of sigfigs, then the value as 1.

So an example is:

```
network.train([
    { input: { Num: 2 }, output: { "1": 1 } },
    { input: { Num: 12 }, output: { "2": 1 } },
    { input: { Num: 432 }, output: { "3": 1 } }
])
```

When `train` runs, for the first item in the array, it sees there is an output for "1" but not for "2" or "3", so it sets "2" and "3" as zero.

In this case it keeps your range between 0 and 1, and allows you to treat 0 as false and 1 as true as if they are boolean values.

I haven't actually checked this with brain js as I'm writing this on my iPhone, but if your neutral net has trained correctly, you should get an output that looks like:

```
const result = network.run({ Num: 43 });
console.log(result);
=> "1": 0.0165, "2": 0.9726, "3": 0.0613
```

Answer (score 1):

You not need any ML for it.. just use the function

function digits(x) {return Math.floor(Math.log10(x) + 1) }

Answer (score 1):

Output should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: How can I make the output between 0 and infinity so that it matches the number of sigfigs.

Comment: I would suggest doing something like this: output between 0 and 0.25 means 1 significant digit, 0.25-0.5 - 2, 0.50-0,75 - 3, 0.75-1 - 4. But I am not sure this is correct or working approach (I am not an expert in brain.js, also learning)